# Proof of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following problem I want to solve with induction method. Would be great if someone helped me with it.

I have $a_0=0$, $a_1=$$1\over 2$ and $|a_{n+1}-a_n|\le|a_n-a_{n-1}|^2$

I need to show $a_n$ is convergent.

I need to show that the sequence is increasing and bounded. I use induction method:

$a_1\lt 1,$ I assume $a_n\lt 1$ and prove that $a_{n+1}\lt1$

$|a_{n+1}-a_n|=|a_n-a_{n-1}|^2\lt1\to|a_{n+1}-a_n|\lt1$ and since $a_n\lt1,a_{n+1}\lt1$

Is this true? How do I use induction to prove increasingness?

Help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The way the problem is currently worded, the sequence need not be increasing. At $n+1$ we can freely choose to go above or below $a_n$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Can you elaborate a bit? I do not understand

Comment: @AndréNicolas Sorry I made a crucial mistake typing the question

Comment: If I may, why do you want to solve it by induction in particular? (and again, it does  not need to be increasing. Take $a_{n+1} = a_n + \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2^n}}$ or something like that, for instance.)

Comment: What if $a_n =.9$ and $a_{n+1} = 1.8$ then $a_{n+1} - a_n < 1$

Answer (score 3):

The sequence $(a_n)$ need not be increasing. For example, $a_2$ could be as high as $\frac{3}{4}$, but it also could as low as $\frac{1}{4}$. There is a similar available choice at every $n+1$.

I would suggest that you try to prove that our sequence is a *Cauchy sequence*.

Comment: I had a typo mistake in the question I corrected.

Comment: The correction does not change anything (whether it's $=$ or $\leq$, the issue is the same).

Comment: I made a minor modification of the answer, to deal with the change to $\le$. But in essence nothing changes. The sequence need not be increasing, and the suggestion to show the sequence is Cauchy still applies.

Comment: An alternative way would be to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty ( a_{n+1}-a_n )$ is an (absolutely) convergent sequence, which by telescoping will give that the sequence $(a_n)_n$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

Define $b_n =|a_{n+1} -a_n | $ then $b_0 =\frac{1}{2} ,$  $b_{n+1} \leq b_n^2 $ thus $b_n \leq\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2^n}$ and this implies convergence of $(a_n )$ because $$|a_{m} -a_n|\leq\sum_{j=0}^{m-n-1} |a_{m-j} -a_{m-j-1}|= \sum_{j=0}^{m-n-1} b_{m-j-1}\leq \sum_{j=0}^{m-n-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2^{m-j-1}}\to 0$$ as $m,n\to \infty.$

Comment: How can I take $b_{n+1}=b^2_{n}$? There is inequality